# GCP Workflows and BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am planning to use Google Cloud Workflows to perform SQL queries on a BigQuery data lake. I have 7 consecutive queries to perform (the query `n` is using the result of `n-`1) to update some tables. However, I am quite sure is there a way to directly call BigQuery from a GCP Workflows `.yaml`?

**exampe.yaml**

```
  - getCurrentTime:
      call: http.get
      args:
      
          url: https://us-central1-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
      result: CurrentDateTime
  - readWikipedia:
      call: http.get
      args:
          url: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
          query:
              action: opensearch
              search: $${CurrentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
      result: WikiResult
  - returnOutput:
      return: $${WikiResult.body[1]}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call directly the [BigQuery query API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query).

But, the product evolves in the right way and now proposed connectors, and there is one for [BigQuery query](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/bigquery/v2/jobs/query). It's in preview, but it's synchronous and will save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these two sub workflows , one to run bigquery job, and the other to wait for that job to finish before running the next job.

```
main:
  steps:
    - initialize:
        assign:
          - project: "project_x"
          - dataset: "dataset_y"
    - query_n:
        call: BQJobsQuery
        args:
          project: ${project}
          sqlQuery: ${"Select * from `dataset_y.view_z`;"}
        result: bq_response
    - get_job_status:
        call: getJobFinalStatus
        args:
          project: ${project}
          job_id: ${bq_response.jobReference.jobId}
        result: job_status_response
    - query_n_1:
        call: BQJobsQuery
        args:
          project: ${project}
          sqlQuery: ${"Select * from `dataset_yy.view_zz`;"}
        result: bq_response
          .
          .
          .

BQJobsQuery:
  params: [project, sqlQuery]
  steps:
    - runQuery:
        try:
          call: http.post
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/queries"}
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
            body:
              useLegacySql: false
              query: ${sqlQuery}
          result: queryResult
        except:
          as: e
          steps:
            - UnhandledException:
                raise: ${e}
    - queryCompleted:
        return: ${queryResult.body}

getJobFinalStatus:
    params: [project, job_id]
    steps:
      - sleep:
          call: sys.sleep
          args:
            seconds: 5
      - getJobCurrentStatus:
          call: http.get
          args:
            url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/"+project+"/jobs/"+job_id}
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
          result: jobStatusRes
      - isJobFinished:
          switch:
            - condition: ${jobStatusRes.body.status.state == "RUNNING"}
              next: sleep
      - jobFinished:
          return: ${jobStatusRes.body}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to run a query from Workflows here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb